# How is wear leveling implemented on eMMC?

Tags: flash

Does anyone understand how wear levelling is implemented in eMMCs?
I've read through various manufacturers datasheets and technical notes, the basics are discussed, Micron also explains the difference between static and dynamic methods.

However, it still leaves multiple questions.

- Is wear levelling carried out automatically?
- Or is wear levelling carried out as part of background ops?
- If background ops is turned off (default), does wear levelling still occur?
- Does wear levelling only occurs when the eMMC is idle?
- What is the definition of idle? (currently, my device is powered down as soon as operations have finished.)
- Which method of wear levelling does Micron implement? (partitioning dependent?)
- Is wear levelling carried out when TRIM is used?

Comment: It probably depends entirely on the eMMC and would require looking at the application notes.

Comment: Most of the post is answerable IMO as is. (Only the Micron-specific questions are not answerable because attributes could vary between devices/models.) The faulty premise is that "wear leveling" is just one operation, but in fact it is actually a group of operations that are performed at different times (e.g. during the `write sector` operation for one aspect, and during "idle" for another aspect).  So the first four bullet points/questions are tightly related, and could share a common answer.